# How to compare strings using =~?

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to create a string that will verify if input time is in the right format. I keep getting the 'else' portion to execute, but never the 'then' portion. I'm not sure where in the string there is a mistake. I execute the script in the shell using ./. I test it with 01:20. It will give me "Time entered is valid." when I input single digit int values. I want it to recognize the 00:00 format. Any suggestions?

```
echo "enter time" ; read time

if [[ '^(([01][0-3])|([2][0-9]))[:][0-5][0-9]$' =~ $time ]]
then
     echo "Time entered is valid."
else
     echo "Time entered is NOT correct."
fi
```

Comment: It has to be `string =~ regexp`, not `regexp =~ string`

Comment: worked. I get it now. thanks alot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=~` is not [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property); the string you want to match must go on the left, the regular expression on the right.

```
if [[ $time =~ '^(([01][0-3])|([2][0-9]))[:][0-5][0-9]$' ]]
```